# pd.Dataframe.update puts the result at the top of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Lets say I have two dataframes like this:

```
n = {'x':['a','b','c','d','e'], 'y':['1','2','3','4','5'],'z':['0','0','0','0','0']}
nf = pd.DataFrame(n)

m = {'x':['b','d','e'], 'z':['10','100','1000']}
mf = pd.DataFrame(n)
```

I want to update the zeroes in the z column in the nf dataframe with the values from the z column in the mf dataframe only in the rows with keys from the column x

when i call

```
nf.update(mf)
```

i get

```
x y z

b 1 10
d 2 100
e 3 1000
d 4 0
e 5 0
```

instead of the desired output

```
x y z

a 1 0
b 2 10
c 3 0
d 4 100
e 5 1000
```

Comment: Its because `.update()` replace values with respect to index and in your case you want it to replace values with respect to `column x`

Comment: So how do I do it then?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your problem, you need to match the indexes of both dataframes, here how you can do it :

```
n = {'x':['a','b','c','d','e'], 'y':['1','2','3','4','5'],'z':['0','0','0','0','0']}
nf = pd.DataFrame(n).set_index('x')

m = {'x':['b','d','e'], 'z':['10','100','1000']}
mf = pd.DataFrame(m).set_index('x')

nf.update(mf)
nf = nf.reset_index()
```